# unable to get a response with people.connections.list

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-people-api

⚠️ I forgot a `process.exit(0)` in the main thread, so the app was terminated before the callback was executed. **This code sample works like a charm**.

---

Here is the code from [`googleapis` nodejs client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) I have issue on: 
[image]

First thing first, **I would like to get the list of contacts for one user using a nodejs application**.

### Set up a OAuth2Client

So I set up a `OAuth2Client` with this code:

```
const {
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
} = require("./keys.json");
const REDIRECT_URL = "http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback";
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
```

Then, using a temporary server, I ask for token using the user's credentials:

```
function getGoogleCode() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Open an http server to accept the oauth callback. In this simple example, the
    // only request to our webserver is to /oauth2callback?code=<code>
    const server = http
      .createServer(async (req, res) => {
        if (req.url.indexOf("/oauth2callback") > -1) {
          // acquire the code from the querystring, and close the web server.
          const { code } = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);
          res.end(
            `Authentication successful! Please return to the console. [code: ${code}]`
          );
          server.close();
          resolve(code);
        }

        reject(new Error("oops", req, res));
      })
      .listen(3000, () => {
        // open the browser to the authorize url to start the workflow
        // Generate the url that will be used for the consent dialog.
        const authorizeUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
          access_type: "offline",
          scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"]
        });
        opn(authorizeUrl);
      });
  });
}
```

Then I finish to set up my client:

```
const code = await getGoogleCode();
const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
```

### When everything's fine

I managed to get a response with the low level API:

```
const personFields = ["emailAddresses", "names"];
const url = `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=${personFields.join(
  ","
)}`;
const res = await oAuth2Client.request({ url });
console.log(chalk.gray(JSON.stringify(res.data.connections, null, 2)));
```

Everything is working like a charm, but, I would like to use the high level API from the same library

### google.people API

As described in [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/people/people/v1/people.people.connections.list), I build the code below:

```
const personFields = ["emailAddresses", "names"];
people.people.connections.list(
  { resourceName: "people/me", personFields },
  (res, err) => {
    console.log("error: ", err);
    console.log("res1: ", res);
  }
);
```

No error, no `res1`, nothing.

---

⚠️ I forgot a `process.exit(0)` in the main thread, so the app was terminated before the callback was executed. **This code sample works like a charm**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you aren't getting logging. But you probably should return the `res` in the callback, otherwise calling `await` on the callback will return `undefined`.

Also make sure to set `personFields` in the `people.people.connections.list` call.

Comment: My mistake, I removed the `async/await` instructions (that was just a try to add them). And it does not work anyway. The callback is never called and `res2` is always `undefined` and no error are displayed. Even with the `personFields` set.

Comment: I am an ~~idiot~~ tired developer, the callback was working, but the process was closed too soon because of a `process.exit(0)` called in the main thread.